# right click context menu work in debug mode but not in release mode

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, telerik-grid

I am displaying a right click context menu on a grid. 
My problem:
 Everything works fine when a debugger is attached. but, with out a debugger When I right click on grid I only see add product, I dont see delete product. 
 This is my code sample XAML:

```
 <telerik:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>
        <telerik:RadContextMenu Opening="RadContextMenu_Opening">
            <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Add Product"                                        
     Command="telerikGrid:RadGridViewCommands.BeginInsert"
                                 CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=purchaseItemGridView}"
                                 IsEnabled="{Binding CanAddItem, Source={StaticResource purchaseItemsViewModel}}"/>

            <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Delete Product"
                                 Command="telerikGrid:RadGridViewCommands.Delete"
                                 CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=purchaseItemGridView}"
                                 IsEnabled="{Binding CanDeleteItem, Source={StaticResource purchaseItemsViewModel}}"/>
        </telerik:RadContextMenu>
    </telerik:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>
```

I am changing the visibility of delete in my pitemsVM

```
public bool CanDeleteItem
    {
      get { return _canDeleteItem; }
      set
      {
          if (_canDeleteItem != value)
          _canDeleteItem = value;
         this.OnPropertyChanged(() => CanDeleteItem);
      }
  }
```

When I am debugging, it works as expected .but, without attaching a debugger I am not able to see the delete on right click.

Comment: Have you noticed, that you are always firing the `PropertyChanged` for `CanDeleteItem`? Why not write: `if (m_foo != value) { m_foo = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Foo"); }` with added curly braces?

Comment: @Martin It didnt work. As I have mentioned, it works in debug mode but not in release mode.